# Absolute URL of a webpage with CefSharp?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, url, cefsharp, absolute-path

I am currently working on a Windows Forms project in C# using Visual Studio. Recently, I switched the default browser in VS to CefSharp's chromium browser as it better suited my needs. While fixing my code, I was unable to figure out how to get the absolute path of a URL (in CefSharp) to change this line of code:

```
if (webBrowser.Url.AbsolutePath == (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Is there a way to get the absolute path from a CefSharp browser and if so, how can I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (webBrowser.Address == (sender as WebBrowser).Address)
```

or, if you need a `Uri` object:

```
var uri1 = new Uri( webBrowser.Address);
var uri2 = new Uri((sender as WebBrowser).Address);

if (uri1.AbsolutePath == uri2.AbsolutePath)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. That is just what I was looking for